# Prove the following statement regarding geometry by induction

Tags: geometry, induction

Prove **by induction** that $n$ straight lines that lie in a plane and are as such that none are parallel and there doesn't exist a point where some three lines cross, divide the plane on $$1+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ parts.

Comment: Are you posing this question to us? I could have chomped it down like _Lo Squalo_ but I need to see what you've tried.

Comment: I don't even know how to write the base case in mathematical notation.

Comment: n = 1: $1+\frac{1(2)}{2}=2$

Comment: If that's what you meant, I did that, and checked by a sketch, but I thought that a algebraic way of checking was needed. Anyways, I verified the base case then, but I don't know how to advance from there.

Comment: Pages 4-8 of "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik should be helpful.